# Regular Expression to match Identity Card number and serial(2 letters)

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need a Regular Expression to validate a romanian Identity Card serial and number like this:
`AX123456`.
There are pre-define sets of 2 letters, followed by 6 digits. You cand find the pre-defined sets of 2 letters in my solution:

```
([AX,TR,AR,XC,ZC,MM,XM,XB,XT,BV,ZV,XR,DP,DR,DT,DX,RD,RR,RT,RX,RK,IF,XZ,KL,KX,CJ,KT,KZ,DX,DZ,HD,VN,GL,ZL,GG,MX,MZ,MH,HR,XH,ZH,NT,AS,AZ,PH,PX,KS,VX,SM,KV,SB,OT,SZ,SV,XV,TM,TZ,DD,GZ,ZS,MS,TC,VS,SX]{2}\d{6})
```

The problem is that the expression accepts, for example 'XA', and I specifically need to accept 'AX', and no other letter combination than the ones between the square brakets.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know you can build trees like this.

Comment: In order to reduce those kind of Regex you can build a tree by ordering the prefix AX,AR,AS,AZ => A[RSXZ], but also reorder the element in the barket for readability. Here is a example on how to split the data and reorganize it https://dotnetfiddle.net/5kFnpd . you can go further by factoring key that has the same Variation `N[T]|O[T]` => `[NO]T`, and remove duplicate `D[DPRTXXZ]` has 2 X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anchors to match the start and the end of the string.

Currently you are using a character class `[]` but you could use an alternation `|` with a non capture group `(?:` and shorten the options a bit by grouping the characters in a character class.

```
^(?:A[RSXZ]|BV|CJ|D[DPRTXZ]|G[GLZ]|H[DR]|IF|K[LSTVXZ]|M[HMSXZ]|[NO]T|P[HX]|R[DKRTX]|S[BMVXZ]|T[CMRZ]|V[NSX]|X[BCHMRTVZ]|Z[CHLSV])\d{6}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD2LHm/1)